# Assert higher-order clause in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This works:

```
assert(p(X) :- q(X)).
```

This does not work:

```
P = p,Q = q, assert(P(X) :- Q(X)).
```

How can I make the latter work?

Comment: `assert(p(X) :- q(X)).` is invalid syntax. `assert((p(X) :- q(X)))` is valid syntax. The former is [SWI's idiosyncrasy](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment#75), that is, there is no other system accepting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the terms first; you can use the "univ" operator, `=..` for this:

```
?- P = p, Q = q, Head =.. [P, X], Body =.. [Q, X], assertz((Head :- Body)).
P = p,
Q = q,
Head = p(X),
Body = q(X).

?- listing(p/1).
:- dynamic p/1.

p(A) :-
    q(A).
```

You need the second pair of parentheses in most implementations, apparently. You will need them anyway if you had for example a conjunction in the body.

```
?- assertz(a :- b).
true.

?- assertz(a :- b, c).
ERROR: assertz/2: Uninstantiated argument expected, found c (2-nd argument)
?- assertz((a :- b, c)).
true.
```

Comment: @repeat I don't see why it shouldn't. In SWI-Prolog, `:-` is declared as an operator; is it in SICStus? (try `current_op(P, T, :-).`

Comment: @repeat Can you link at least one of the questions that actually elaborates on the need for extra parentheses? I was not able to find anything at the link you provided. And anyway, the extra parenthesis are in general needed if there is a conjunction somewhere in the argument: for example, a conjunction as the second argument to `bagof/3`.

Comment: @repeat What is meant by "standard syntax"? Is `a :- b` standard syntax, or `:-(a, b)`? Can you write `assertz(:-(a, b))` in SICStus?

Comment: Please note that `assertz(a :-b)` being accepted as valid syntax is not necessarily a case of non-compliance. It might be a case of a (valid) implementation specific extension qua ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 5.5.1. However, I am unaware of a precise definition for such an extension. There are much too many further cases to resolve that are not resolved in SWI. As such an example, think of [#92](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment#92) where other systems differ.  And it would the burden of a party claiming conformance to provide such a consistent definition.

Comment: @repeat It seems we have an answer. My feeling is that `a :- b` is not ambiguous (as far as I can see), so there should be no need for the extra parenthesis.